# How to fix linking errors with gfortran compiler?

Tags: eclipse, dll, fortran, cygwin, gfortran

I downloaded Eclipse and Cygwin for windows 7 64 bit. I wrote the next Fortran program:

```
program main
    print*, 'Hello World'
end program main
```

and got the next error when I tried to build the program:

```
make all 
Building target: examples
Invoking: GNU Fortran Linker
gfortran  -o "examples"  ./main.o   
gfortran: fatal error: -fuse-linker-plugin, but cyglto_plugin.dll not found
compilation terminated.
makefile:29: recipe for target 'examples' failed
make: *** [examples] Error 1
```

I looked for the file cyglto_plugin.dll, and found it in the folder:

```
C:\cygwin64\lib\gcc\x86_64-pc-cygwin\4.9.3
```

I tried to add this folder to the PATH environment variable but still got the same error.

Searching the web I found out that the problem can be solved by installing as a dependency the library cyglto_plugin.dll, which is used for Link-Time-Optimization, and can be found in the package gcc-core. However, I have no idea how to do it, can someone instruct me please ?

Using the command prompt I disabled this library by typing:

```
$ gfortran main.f90 -fno-use-linker-plugin -o main
```

doing so I got a bunch of new errors:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find crtbegin.o: No such file or directory
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lquadmath
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find crtend.o: No such file or directory
```

Do someone has an idea how to fix these errors ?

Comment: Try to place it in LIBRARY_PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH, not PATH.

Comment: It looks like you have installed multiple versions of cygwin.  You found the dll in a directory for gcc 4.9.3 and your linker errors indicate version 4.9.2.  I'd suggest cleaning up both versions and installing a single version from scratch.

Comment: I'm sorry about the stupid question, but I really don't know how to clean my computer from both versions. I don't find any Cygwin in the add/remove program utility, and couldn't find any uninstall application in the cygwin64 library. Can you instruct me please how to do it?